# Errors while using styled and typed components in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have a styled component that looks like this:

```
export const TestClassButton = styled(Button)({ ... })
```

And I use it like this:

```
<Tooltip arrow title={"status"}>
   <TestClassButton
     id={"button-status-dialog"}
     onClick={() => setShowDialog(!showDialog)}
   >
     <ListAltIcon />
   </TestClassButton>
 </Tooltip>
```

**Result:**

[image]

If I try to style a little bit more my styled component like this:

```
export const TestClassButton = styled((props) => (
  <Button variant={"outlined"} {...props} />
))({ ... });
```

Then the component where I use it says this:

[image]

And the Tooltip stops working. Any idea why is this happening? Isn't this the propper way to use styled components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My soultion to avoid extra typos and errors was to separate the Material UI properties from the styled component like this:

```
const StyledButton = ({ children, ...props }) => (
   <Button size={"small"} variant={"contained"} {...props}>
      {children}
   </Button>
);

export const TestClassButton = styled(StyledButton)({ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Heh, just posted that it is unobvious on mui page (how to extend components with styled)

```
const TestClassButton = styled(Button, { 
  shouldForwardProp: (props) => 
    ['myCustomProp'].every(key => key !== prop),
})<ButtonProps & { myCustomProp?: boolean  }>(({ theme, myCustomProp }) => theme.unstable_sx({
   background: myCustomProp ? 'red' : 'green',
}))

const Component = () => {
   return <TestClassButton myCustomProp>TEST</TestClassButton>
}
```

you can also do that like this:

```
const TestClassButton = styled(Button, { 
  shouldForwardProp: (props) => 
    ['myCustomProp'].every(key => key !== prop),
})<ButtonProps & { myCustomProp?: boolean  }>(({ theme, myCustomProp }) => ({ 
 variant: 'outlined',
 style: theme.unstable_sx({
   background: myCustomProp ? 'red' : 'green',
  }),
})

const Component = () => {
   return <TestClassButton myCustomProp>TEST</TestClassButton>
}
```